# Opening ZIX files in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu

Is there a app to open zix extension files in Ubuntu, can't seem to find any?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mean a .zix compressed file, they do seem to have a [Linux version](http://www.winzix.com/index.php?go=expert) available, although from what I've read the zix software is full of adware.

[Mininova discussion of the subject.](http://forum.mininova.org/index.php?showtopic=234994807&hl=winzix)
[Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Winzix)

Yuck!

If you're referring to some other extension, let us know.

Comment: I'm referring to the .zix compressed file, but will rather then not use it

Answer (score 2):

It tends to be a virus, so odds are it's not an actual useful file.

[Source](http://garbledzombie.wordpress.com/2007/11/18/do-not-trust-winzix-and-the-zix-file-format/)

Answer (score 0):

**UnZixWin** is a free alternative in **WinZix** allowing to recover folders contained in an archive `ZIX`.

Certain downloaded files (in format `*.zix`, `*.avi` or `*.torrent`) ask to install **WinZix** or **3wplayer** to be read. These two readers are in fact traps intended to infect their users.  So, Kenneth Sorling, a Sweed, put this free software in the point, without spyware, allowing to open archive `ZIX`, to show his contents and to choose files exactly to be extracted.

On top of that, it will alert you if one of the files contained in archive is infected by one of the classical viruses which he knows.

Here is the link for downloading [**UnZixWin**](http://en.kioskea.net/download/download-382-unzixwin):

Comment: the question was rather specific about the OS though, does this work in wine?